# fast way to iterate through list, find duplicates and perform calculations

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, performance, numpy

I have two lists, one of areas and one of prices which are the same size.

For example:
area = [1500,2000,2000,1800,2000,1500,500]
price = [200,800,600,800,1000,750,200]

I need to return a list of prices for each unique area not including the original area.

So for 1500, the lists that I need returned are: [750] and [200]
For the 2000, the lists that I need returned are [600,1000], [800,1000] and [800,600]
For the 1800 and 500, the lists I need returned are both empty lists [].

The goal is then to determine whether a value is an outlier subject to the absolute value of the price - mean(excluding the price itself) being less than 5 * population standard deviation(calculated excluding the price itself)

```
    import statistics
area = [1500,2000,2000,1800,2000,1500,500]
price = [200,800,600,800,1000,750,200]         
outlier_idx = []
for idx, val in enumerate(area):
    comp_idx = [i for i, x in enumerate(area) if x == val]
    comp_idx.remove(idx)
    comp_price = [price[i] for i in comp_idx]
    if len(comp_price)>2:
        sigma = statistics.stdev(comp_price)
        p_m = statistics.mean(comp_price)
        if abs(price[idx]-p_m) > 5 * sigma:
            outlier_idx.append(idx)

area = [i for j, i in enumerate(area) if j not in outlier_idx]
price = [i for j, i in enumerate(price) if j not in outlier_idx]
```

The problem is that this calculation takes up a lot of time and I am dealing with arrays that can be quite large.

I am stuck as to how I can increase the computational efficiency.

I am open to using numpy, pandas or any other common packages.

Additionally, I have tried the problem in pandas:

```
df['p-p_m'] = ''
df['sigma'] = ''
df['outlier'] = False
for name, group in df.groupby('area'):
    if len(group)>1:
        idx = list(group.index)
        for i in range(len(idx)):
            tmp_idx = idx.copy()
            tmp_idx.pop(i)
            df['p-p_m'][idx[i]] = abs(group.price[idx[i]] - group.price[tmp_idx].mean())
            df['sigma'][idx[i]] = group.price[tmp_idx].std(ddof=0)
            if df['p-p_m'][idx[i]] > 3*df['sigma'][idx[i]]:
                df['outlier'][idx[i]] = True
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This code is how to must created the list for each area:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'area': area, 'price': price})

price_to_delete = [item for idx_array in df.groupby('price').groups.values() for item in idx_array[1:]]
df.loc[price_to_delete, 'price'] = None

df = df.groupby('area').agg(lambda x: [] if all(x.isnull()) else x.tolist())
df
```

I don't understand what are you want, but this part is to calculate outliers for each price in each area:

```
df['outlier'] = False
df['outlier'] = df['price'].map(lambda x: abs(np.array(x) - np.mean(x)) > 3*np.std(x) if len(x) > 0 else [])
df
```

I hope this help you, in any way!

Comment: If you don't understand what OP wants, ask for clarification instead of posting an answer please.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that combines [**Numpy**](https://numpy.org/) and [**Numba**](http://numba.pydata.org/). Although correct, I did not test it against alternative approaches regarding efficiency, but Numba usually results in significant speedups for tasks that require looping through data. I have added one extra point which is an outlier, according to your definition.

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit

# data input
price = np.array([200,800,600,800,1000,750,200, 2000])
area = np.array([1500,2000,2000,1800,2000,1500,500, 1500])

@jit(nopython=True)
def outliers(price, area):
    is_outlier = np.full(len(price), False)
    for this_area in set(area):
        indexes = area == this_area
        these_prices = price[indexes]
        for this_price in set(these_prices):
            arr2 = these_prices[these_prices != this_price]
            if arr2.size > 1:
                std = arr2.std()
                mean = arr2.mean()
                indices = (this_price == price) & (this_area == area)
                is_outlier[indices] = np.abs(mean - this_price) > 5 * std

    return is_outlier 

> outliers(price, area)
> array([False, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True])
```

The code should be fast in case you have several identical price levels for each area, as they will be updated all at once.

I hope this helps.